# Eclipse PHP editor suddenly broken

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse, and after a restart, I suddenly can't open PHP files.  When I try, I get a popup error box saying:

```
Error opening the editor.  (Time of error: [now])
Reason:
No editor descriptor for id org.eclipse.php.editor
```

Any advice for what's going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the latest Eclipse? This seems like a bug from a couple of years ago, and has to do with a certain code within one of your PHP files.

Check this:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326247

Comment: Try checking Eclipse´s log for an exception also: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F

Comment: This question got me pointed to the right answer.  No, I'm NOT using the latest version, even though I downloaded it and had been using it before.  Inadvertently switching back to the old version caused mayhem.  Thanks.

Comment: Also: if you're using the latest Eclipse, but installed it from scratch and *forgot to reinstall PDT*, this will also happen. *facepalm* Don't let the fact you have a "PHP" perspective button fool you into thinking that PDT is actually installed.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to delete the hidden .metadata folder in your workspace directory.
rename it and try to open eclipse again. it should create a new one. if still does not work, revert the changes.

Answer (score 0):

*facepalm*

When you update to the latest version of Eclipse, don't keep using the link to the old version.  That causes problems.